# TensorFlow 2.0 output specification in NLP model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, tensorflow

I just started playing with `TensorFlow 2.0` now that the new api is out. However, I do not get the model output specification.

The model below is a simple example from their site with the `mnist`dataset. If I understand correctly, there are 60000 images (28x28) pixels. Each input image has **one** corresponding digit (0-9) output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

print(y_train.shape) # <-- output dimension (60000,) 

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax') # <-- output nodes 10 
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=5, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Note from the print out, we have one dimensional training array i.e.:(60000,) but in the last layer we specify 10 nodes! Why? I understand why 10 nodes if the output was one_hot'ed - but as shown we have a single digit.

If someone can explain whats going on here - I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works because the model uses the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function. It is like a regular categorical crossentropy loss that **doesn't** require the labels to be one-hot encoded to work!

Alternatively you could one-hot encode the labels and train on a `categorical_crossentropy` loss:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# One-hot encode the labels
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

print(y_train.shape) # <-- output dimension (60000, 10) 

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax') # <-- output nodes 10 
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',  # <-- changed loss function
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=5, epochs=5)  # still works
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: The output layer is 10-wide, though, with probabilities for each digit.

Comment: Ahh I see - I did quick search after you mentioned it and found this: https://jovianlin.io/cat-crossentropy-vs-sparse-cat-crossentropy/